# Cardinality of a subset of reals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Statement: $\{1/n: n \in \mathbb Z_+\} \cup \{0\}$ is compact in reals.
>
> Proof:
>
> Let $A =\{1/n: n \in \mathbb Z_+\} \cup \{0\}$. Suppose $U$ is an open cover of $A$. Then there's some open set $U_1$ s.t. $0 \in U_1$. **Then $U_1$ contains all but at most finitely many points of $A$**. Let $1/m$ be the smallest point in $A \setminus U_1$. Each point of $A \setminus U_1$ is in at least one open set. For each point $1/i$ choose one open set s.t. at most $m + 1$ open sets cover $A.$

My question: how do we know $A - U_1$ cannot be infinite? Thanks.

Comment: How does $U_1$ look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $U_1$ is an open nbhd of $0$, there must be an $\epsilon>0$ such that $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\subseteq U_1$. Then $\frac1n\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\subseteq U_1$ for each $n>\frac1{\epsilon}$. There are only finitely many positive integers $n$ such that $n\le\frac1\epsilon$, and those are the only members of $A$ that might not be in $U_1$.